# ¿De dónde proviene la palabra 'meacamas'?

Tags: etimología

¿Cuales son el origen y significado de la primera parte de esa palabra, es decir, lo del 'me'?

Si la primera parte es una forma abreviada de meter, o la de otro verbo semejante, en ese caso no está claro cómo se ha desarrollado hasta su forma contemporánea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meacamas is a compound word: *Mea* + *Camas*. It literally means "Someone who pees on his/her bed"

Mea = Third person of the present tense conjugation of the verb *Mear* (To Pee)

Camas = Beds (plural of noun Cama -Bed-)

So, meacamas would literally mean "Someone who pees on his/her bed"

Compound words are usually formed by taking a verb in the third person singular and appending a plural noun. For example:

*Lavavajillas* = *Lava* + *Vajillas* (Dishwasher)

*Rompecorazones* = *Rompe* + *Corazones* (Heartbreaker)

Comment: Beaten by the Captcha :)

Comment: No veo el por qué de la suposición que la cama a mear es la propia :)

Comment: Y mi favorito:  matasanos

Answer (score 3):

I think you stopped short! "Mea" from the verb "mear" , to urinate.
hence "wet the bed" based on the use of its leaves as a diuretic.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's worth noting that *mear* is probably quite a bit more vulgar that *orinar*. I'd translate it as "to piss".

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración. ¿Es la dicha palabra considerada como algo vulgar solamente en el dialecto colombiano, o en el español global también?

Comment: La verdad es que yo no sé. En Colombia _mear_ se usa mas que todo entre amigos en situaciones poco formales. La verdad es que casi nunca lo escucho de la boca de una mujer. Como que en el inglés es muy típico oir "I'm gonna take a piss" de un hombre pero rara vez se oye de una niña. Yo no puedo confirmar que sea igual en los otros países de habla español.